# Http post Angular2

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf

I am migrating an Ionic v1 application to Ionic v2. In one of my methods I make a call to a WCF service. In AngularJS I do it like this:

```
$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: url,
 data: JSON.stringify({ dato: 11 }),
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
})
```

And in Angular2 like this:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({ dato: 11 });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post(url, data, options)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
}, error => {
  console.log("Error");
});
```

However, I receive from my C# service an error and says that the format I send to my functions is 'RAW' while waiting for it to send JSON with Angular 2

This error occurred to me in AngularJS but it was solved by adding the code I previously left in this post.

**EDIT**

My WCF service :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetCaptaciones", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json , BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
List<Captacion> GetCaptaciones(int id_captador);
```

AND

```
let data = JSON.stringify({ id_captador: 11 });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post(url + "/GetCaptaciones", data, options).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Not working,

But if I test from POSTMAN this works

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({ dato: 11 });
```

and this:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
```

are terribly contradictory and inconsistent.

Please try to be consistent when you make an HTTP request against a web server about how you are going to encode the request. So if intend to send a JSON body make sure that you specify the proper `Content-Type` request header, so that the server would know how to process this payload:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I change that content type, I get the error "405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: Well, then you will need to fix your webserver, so that it accepts POST requests. The 405 status code usually indicates that the webserver doesn't understand the HTTP verb you are using.

Comment: I will add my service so you can see it.

Comment: Update mi question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Darin has said I would say you are not using `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` correctly.

See your wcf method expects a single parameter so you could go ahead without wrappedrequest property.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetCaptaciones", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Captacion> GetCaptaciones(int id_captador);
```

Wrapped request means there should be some wrapper object on top of the input properties which WCF method takes as argument.

So something like this

```
 var input =
        {
            "CaptacionesInput": 
            {
                "id_captador": 11
            }
        };
```

Now wcf method becomes like

```
List<Captacion> GetCaptaciones(CaptacionesInputType CaptacionesInput);
```